# make error when install fuerte from source

Tags: ubuntu, ros-fuerte, boost, ubuntu-precise, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

PC: ubuntu 12.04

I try to install fuerte form source according to the wiki
.But when I use the "make -j8", a error will happen:

```
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_increment(void*&, void*&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::filesystem::file_status&, boost::filesystem::file_status&)'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_close(void*&, void*&)'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::create_directory_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::dir_itr_first(void*&, void*&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, boost::filesystem::file_status&, boost::filesystem::file_status&)'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::get_current_path_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&)'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::not_found_error()'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_generic_category()'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::system::get_system_category()'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::program_options::options_description::options_description(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, unsigned int)'
../lib/librospack.so: undefined reference to `boost::filesystem::detail::status_api(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::system::error_code&)'
```

I have installed libboost, and who can help me to solve this error.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/52783/make-error-when-install-fuerte-from-source/) by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2013-01-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-01-19**:
Is it the right version of boost (1.46.1)? How and where did you install it?

**Comment by [Robin Hu](https://answers.ros.org/users/3839/robin-hu/) on 2013-01-19**:
yes ,i use "apt-get" to install it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default version of boost is 1.48 on Precise 12.04 it's not expected to work on a different version. 1.46 is available via apt but there are API changes between them which need to be patched if you switch.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0